# Add to cart without leaving page

Tags: php, sql, ajax, pdo

I am trying to make an ajax call to add an item to cart without the user having to leave the page. I have manage to write the follow code but It is nothing working. On the addtocart.php I have manunally enter the `ProdID`, `size` and `Category` but not echo out. Can someone please take a look at both my ajax and addtocart.php

**AJAX**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('.ajax').click(function(){
$.ajax({ 
url: '../main/php/addtocart.php',
         type: 'post',
         data:{
            length:$('#length').val(),
                Category:$('#Category').val(),
                id:$('#id').val(),
                Qty:$('#Qty').val()

                  },
         success: function(data) {

                  }
});
});
});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    include('dbconnect.php');
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $length = $_POST["size"];
    $qty = $_POST['Qty'];
    $Category = $_POST['Category'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("
SELECT  ProductName, Category.Name, size, Price
FROM itembag, Product, Category
WHERE Product.ProdID =:id
AND size= :length  AND Category.Name = :Category Limit  1");
$stmt->bindParam('id',$id);
$stmt->bindParam('length',$length); 
$stmt->bindParam('Category',$Category); 
$stmt->execute();
$i=0;
 foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
             if ($i == 0) {  
echo 'status:1,id:'.$row['ProdID'].',Price:'.$row['Price'].',txt:\'\
\
<table width="100%" id="table_'.$row['ProdID'].'">\
  <tr>\
    <td width="60%">'.$row['ProductName'].'</td>\
    <td width="40%">$'.$row['Price'].'</td>\
    <td width="10%">$'.$row['Category'].'</td>\
  </tr>\
</table>\'';
}
}
?>
```

ADDITIONAL INFO: An item maybe have 1 id but it comes in different sizes and many category.

Comment: your `data` object is empty in your ajax call: `data: {}`

Comment: @ChristianGärtner take a long now and also what about the addtocart.php? is that okay

Comment: your `addtocart.php` is expecting 4 parameters, you've passed only 2 from your AJAX, can you post your `HTML` code also?

Comment: @Þaw i have just added it

Comment: `Category.Name` doesn' t work in PHP you have send a json encoded version of the object and json_decode it on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `HTML` your `AJAX` would look like something like this:

*Note: If you're using `AJAX` you must refer to your selector by `id` not by `name`*

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#button').click(function()
    {
        var id = $('#id').val();
        var length = $('#length').val();
        var qty = $('#Qty').val();
        var cat = $('#Category').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '../main/php/addtocart.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { id:id, length:length, qty:qty, cat:cat },
            success: function(data)
            {
                //whatever you want to do
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Its may also be better if you would do like this in the beginning of your `PHP`

```
if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['length']) && isset($_POST['Qty']) && isset($_POST['cat']))
{    
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $length = $_POST['length'];
    $qty = $_POST['Qty'];
    $Category = $_POST['Category'];
```

Comment: I have the button as 
<button id="button" name="button">Add to cart</button> and it is not within a form

Comment: its ok because you're using `AJAX`

Comment: I see u r posting the `var`

Comment: yes because based on your `PHP` code those are the data the you're expecting from the `AJAX` request

Comment: @ Þaw i just used `window.alert(data);` to see if the data was passed and it returned blank

Comment: try to alert the variables `var` in your AJAX to make sure they contain values. `id, length, qty, and cat`

Comment: The php for the addtocart doesn't work so i used the orginally cart php and it works

Answer (score 1):

Is missing the data to POST

```
data: {
//Here you have to put your data
},
```

You have to get the value you want to POST
for example:

```
('.ajax').click(function(){
 pid = $('#pid').val();//#pid->is the id of your input, the same bellow
length = $('#length').val();
Qty = $('#Qty').val();
Category = $('#Category').val();
$.ajax({ 
  url: '../main/php/addtocart.php',
  data:{
    pdi:pdi,
    length:length,
    Qty :Qty ,
    Category : Category},
    type: 'post',
}).done(function(data) {
 $(data).html('#containerShoppingCart');//Callback Replace the html of your shoppingCart Containe with the response of addtocart.php
}).fail(function(){ alert("failed!"); });//Some action to indicate is Failing
```

You can see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ to get more information

Comment: Ater passes the value to addtocart.php, how can i display the value as a form of the cart? @Emilio Gort

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using jQuery load might help you load/update your cart.
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I am trying to add an item to cart